# Estimating divergence of set of vectors

Tags: differentiation, vector-fields, numerical-method

I have a set of points where directions and intensities of a flow are given (in 3D). Is it possible to estimate the divergence of the flow defined by those vectors? I only need a rough estimate and I can assume continuity and smoothness.

I expected this to be a common question, but I wasn't able to find any literature, which makes me suspect I used uncommon phrases to describe my problem...

Comment: So, you essentially have a vector field, but defined on a lattice rather than a smooth set?

Comment: That would be a more precise formulation, yeah! The lattice has only about 10-100 nodes.

Comment: @Kyra  can you have a look at [this site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection%E2%80%93diffusion_equation#General) ? I suppose that diffusion is not part of your problem, and also that the problem is stationary in time and without sources, but what remains from the equation maybe helps.

Comment: @Kyra  Could it be that the equation $\nabla (\vec v f) = 0$ where $f$ is the intensity, might be what you seek?

Comment: Thank you @Sofia! This is indeed what I am trying to solve. My question is how to find an approximate solution for this equation on an discrete lattice (thanks for the formulation @ACuriousMind)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of divergence is
$$\textrm{div}\,\vec{F} = \lim_{V \to p}\iint_{S(V)} \frac{\vec{F}\cdot\vec{n}}{|V|}dS, \qquad [1]$$
where $\vec{F}$ is the vector field, $V$ is the volume surrounding the point $p$ where the divergence is calculated, $\vec{n}$ is a unit-length normal vector of the surface, $S(V)$, of the volume, and $|V|$ is the total volume.

To approximate this with a sampling of the vector field, instead of shrinking the volume to a point, $$\lim_{V \to p},$$ choose a small volume that surrounds the point in question and make it large enough to encompass many samples of the vector field (divergence is zero for a constant field).
$$\textrm{div}\,\vec{F} \approx \iint_{S(V)} \frac{\vec{F}\cdot\vec{n}}{|V|}dS.$$
If you are working in Cartesian coordinates, you could make your life easier and choose a cube aligned with your axes so $\vec{n}$ is constant on each side. Take the average of the vector field across the surface, interpolating as needed. If your cube as side lengths $x$, then your calculation becomes:
$$\sum_{i=1}^6 \frac{\vec{F_i}\cdot\hat{e_i}x^2}{x^3} = \frac{1}{x}\sum_{i=1}^6 \vec{F_i}\cdot\hat{e_i}$$
where $\vec{F_i}$ is the average vector on each surface and $\hat{e_i}$ is the unit normal vector on each cube face, $[\pm 1, 0, 0]$ for the faces perpendicular to the x-axis.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#Definition_of_divergence